# What are the 14 different types of saxophone?

Tags: instruments, saxophone

I heard my saxophone instructor say that there are 14 sizes of saxophone. But, I've only heard of 4 (soprano, alto, tenor, baritone). What are the other 10 types?

Comment: saxaboom?  ;)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLmCJKT5ssw

Comment: @b3ko I want one of those things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, saxophones are either in Eb or Bb, but C and F saxophones were produced in the early 20th century, so some of the standard horns had C and F counterparts. The most common of these was the C melody sax, which was a C version of the soprano that was popular because it used to read piano music (without transposition). There was also an F mezzo-soprano that has been used by a few performers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezzo-soprano_saxophone).

Some other obscure ones include sopranino (smaller than a soprano), contrabass sax (bigger than bass), and even the sub-contrabass sax (which was used by the Nuclear Whales Saxophone Orchestra).

There are other types that have been specially produced, like this G mezzo-soprano: http://thesax.info/blog/jessen-g-mezzo-soprano/

Comment: I believe the number 14 comes from Adolphe Sax's original vision of the saxophone family; that is: sopranino, soprano, alto, tenor, bari, and bass, each in Eb/Bb versions and C/F versions. Not all of these versions were ever actually mass produced though.

Answer (score 3):

From Yamaha there *were* 14 types, but according to Yamaha now only 5 are in wide spread use: soprano, alto, tenor, baritone, and bass.

- https://www.yamaha.com/en/musical_instrument_guide/saxophone/structure/structure002.html

I tried to dig deeper to verify the claim of 14, but I could not find anything conclusive. Some sources claim the number comes from a patent that Sax obtained, but even that cannot be easily confirmed. In fact, I found this article about the  saxophone patents: [McBride, The Early Saxophone in Patents 1838-1850 Compared](https://www.jstor.org/stable/841237).

There is a image online which is supposed to be from Sax's original patent...

[image]

- https://www.selmer.fr/histdetail.php?id=3
- https://i2.wp.com/www.thesax.info/photoblog/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/1846-1VV1.jpg

...no definitive claim could be made from just that picture, nor does it give names.

You can easily Google for a list of names of instruments in the saxophone family and find page like...

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxophone

...but I'm not going to attempt making a list here, because I can't confirm anything other than the well known list of five above. At least with those I have seen them all with my own eyes!

Comment: That could be augmented by one - the straight soprano, as opposed to the sax-shaped usual.

Comment: @tim There are also straight alto saxophones. I would call these variations, but not different sizes, so they wouldn't change the list.

Comment: Saxe patented what he designed;  many more (of absurd range) were built later on.

Comment: @Tim "sax shaped usual"?  I've never seen a soprano saxophone that wasn't straight.

Comment: @phoog - there are more than a few on the market. I used to play in a jazz band where the sax player had a standard tenor, and a 'bent' soprano, both obviously in the same transposition, so easier to interchange.

Answer (score 2):

There are 9 Saxophones in the primary family (marked with a dagger (†)). And there are as many as 15 types of saxophones, depending on how you define the word. The first four in the list are the most common. Instruments marked with an asterisk (*) are not always considered true saxophones and any one of them may not have been considered one of the 14 by the instructor.

The list is as follows:

[**Tenor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenor_saxophone)† - In the key of B♭ (one octave below) - sounding range from A♭2 to E5

[image: Tenor Sax]

[**Alto**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alto_saxophone)† - In the key of E♭ - sounding range from D♭3 to A♭5

[image: Alto Sax]

[**Soprano**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soprano_saxophone)† - In the key of B♭ - sounding range from B♭3 to G♭6

[image: https://www.wwbw.com/Yamaha-YSS-475II-Intermediate-Soprano-Saxophone-469059.wwbw]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](https://www.wwbw.com/Yamaha-YSS-475II-Intermediate-Soprano-Saxophone-469059.wwbw)

[**Baritone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baritone_saxophone)† - In the key of E♭ (one octave below) - sounding range from C2 to A4

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baritone_saxophone]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baritone_saxophone)

[Sopranissimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopranissimo_saxophone)†* - in the key of B♭ (one octave above) - sounding range from B♭4 to D♭7

[image: http://www.ultimatesongwriting.com/sopranino-saxophone/]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](http://www.ultimatesongwriting.com/sopranino-saxophone/)

[Bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_saxophone)† - Key of B♭ (two octaves below) - Sounding range B♭1 to F4 (I think)

[image: https://www.wwbw.com/Allora-Vienna-Series-Intermediate-Baritone-Saxophone-585578.wwbw]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](https://www.wwbw.com/Allora-Vienna-Series-Intermediate-Baritone-Saxophone-585578.wwbw)

[Sopranino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopranino_saxophone)† - In the key of E♭ - sounding range from D♭4 to A♭6

[image: https://www.wwbw.com/P-Mauriat-Professional-Eb-Sopranino-Saxophone-J06194.wwbw]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](https://www.wwbw.com/P-Mauriat-Professional-Eb-Sopranino-Saxophone-J06194.wwbw)

[Contrabass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrabass_saxophone)† - In the key of E♭ (two octaves below) - sounding range D♭1 to A♭3 (I think)

[image: http://bassic-sax.info/blog/2013/a-jelle-stainer-compact-contrabass-saxophone/]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](http://bassic-sax.info/blog/2013/a-jelle-stainer-compact-contrabass-saxophone/)

[Tubax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubax)* - Available in E♭, B♭, or C (all two octaves below) - sounding range of E♭ (the lowest) model is the same as Contrabass - D♭1 to A♭3 (I think)

[image: http://www.jayeaston.com/galleries/sax_family/subcontrabass_sax.html]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](http://www.jayeaston.com/galleries/sax_family/subcontrabass_sax.html)

[C Melody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_melody_saxophone) - Key of C (one octave below) - sounding range B♭2 to F5

[image: https://www.sax.co.uk/sakkusu-c-melody-saxophone-gold-lacquer.ir]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](https://www.sax.co.uk/sakkusu-c-melody-saxophone-gold-lacquer.ir)

[Slide Saxophone](https://web.archive.org/web/20070628175600/http://www.jasonharron.com/Slide01.JPG)*

[image: http://bassic-sax.info/blog/2010/ever-wondered-what-a-slide-saxophone-sounds-like/]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](http://bassic-sax.info/blog/2010/ever-wondered-what-a-slide-saxophone-sounds-like/)

[Saxello](http://www.hnwhite.com/Saxello%20Page.htm)*

[image: https://www.getasax.com/product/king-saxello-soprano-tipped-bell-bent-neck-near-pristine-silver-plate/]

[<sup>Image Source</sup>](https://www.getasax.com/product/king-saxello-soprano-tipped-bell-bent-neck-near-pristine-silver-plate/)

[Connosax](https://reverb.com/item/637095-conn-conn-o-sax-1929-silver) (aka Conn-O-Sax)*

[image: Conn-O-Sax]

[Subcontrabass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subcontrabass_saxophone)† - Key of B♭ (three octaves below!) - Sounding range B♭0 to F3 (I think)

[image: Subcontrabass Sax]

[Mezzo Soprano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezzo-soprano_saxophone) - Essentially a Soprano sax in F - Sounding range E♭3 to B♭5 - This may not have been counted separately from the soprano sax by the instructor

[image: Mezzo-Soprano Sax]

Comment: I'm not sure this accurately answers the OPs question because he asked about different sizes, not variations. For instance, the Tubax is a variation on the bass sax, the Saxello is a brand name version of the soprano, and the Conn-O-Sax is a variation on the F mezzo soprano that was only produced for a couple years. Similarly, the Slide Sax was a novelty instrument from the 1920s that was never widely played (and it was the same size as a soprano). The Sopranissimo sax is smaller than a sopranino, but it is only made by one company and goes by the brand name Soprillo sax.

Comment: I agree that slide saxes don't really count.  That's a mechanism, not a range.

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you explained what the nonobvious ones are, such as "tubax", "saxello," "connosax" .

Comment: @Peter there are several different slide saxophones - in fact i thnk they were featured in a question on this site 6 months ago.  I recal one model was purely trombone-ish  (total bore length changes) while another opens or closes holes on the lower body as it slides over the upper body (which doesn'thave holes)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Cool. I was only familiar with the latter type: https://www.dornpub.com/SaxjPDF/slidesax.pdf

Comment: This is a great example of a question with no really definitive answer.  Exactly what counts as a saxophone?

Comment: @ScottWallace - moot point. I wonder if my *xaphoon* would be counted..?

Comment: @Peter OP asks about *size* and *types*. Variations fits there, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tim - I actually thought that too about my xaphoon.  But seeing as the xaphoon is cylindrical in bore and not conical, I think it would rather count as one of the 317 kinds of clarinet...

Comment: @ScottWallace - the original xaphoons, made from bamboo, would be very slightly conical. Only 317? Looks like another question needs posing...

Comment: @Tim - yeah, mine's a bit conical too, but not enough to disturb its acoustical cylindricity.  It plays an octave lower than a flute- or a conical reed instrument like the sax does.  I have another candidate for a sax: a sort of medieval soprano sax of wood with no keys.  Sounds very much like a soprano sax.

Answer (score 1):

Cecil Forsyth's orchestration a manual from the 1910's mentions 7 varieties of saxophone (Sopranino, Soprano, Alto, Tenor, Baritone, Bass, Contrabass), in 2 series (a military series in E♭/B♭, and an orchestral series in F/C):

This is a total of 14 (7×2) types of saxophone, and I bet this is how your instructor is coming up with that figure.

But, even in this hundred-year-old book the "extreme" Sopranino and Contrabass are only really mentioned to complete the set; they aren't at all common.  The entire F/C "orchestral series" has also basically died out these days.

---

From Cecil Forsyth's *Orchestration* (1914, 1st ed., England)

- Plate VI (facing p. 167):

> [image: The Saxophones: No. 2 Soprano, No. 3 Alto, No. 4 Tenor, No. 5 Baritone, No. 6 Bass]

- p. 167:

> Five varieties of this instrument are made in this country {England}.  Like the Saxhorns they are built alternately in E♭ and B♭.  These five varieties are, in the list given below, numbered 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  Two other instruments are used in France and Belgium.  They are both "extreme" instruments, one in the treble, the other in the bass.  We may add them to our list as Nos. 1 and 7.  The Complete catalogue is then as follows:
>
> [(1) Sopranino in E♭.]
>  (2) Soprano in B♭.
>  (3) Alto in E♭.
>  (4) Tenor in B♭.
>  (5) Baritone in E♭.
>  (6) Bass in B♭.
> [(7) Contrabass in E♭.]
>
> The whole series of theses seven military instruments, alternately in E♭ and B♭, is also reduplicated abroad by orchestral Saxophones alternately in F and C.  It must be mentioned, however, that even abroad No. 7 (the "Contrabass") scarcely exists except as a workshop-curiosity.   The Bass Saxophone in B♭ (No. 6) is as heavy an instrument as any Wind-player would care to tackle.  The "Contrabass," therefore, has been omitted entirely from the list of these instruments given on pages 7 and 8.
>
> The general appearance of the Saxophones can be gathered from the illustration on Plate VI.  The five instruments shown on the Plate are numbered to correspond with the list given above.

Comment: Fifteen. Let us not forget the [saxamophone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21x7KObESV0).

Comment: @Aaron Or [this one](https://youtu.be/FB_JTIXkZ-Y?si=MJjbtBRIUaCgyC7w&t=26)  in V-flat.

Answer (score 0):

i understand there supposedly 14 but i found more...Sopranino, soprano, curved soprano, mezzo soprano, alto, c-melody, tenor, bari, bass, contrabass, and sub-contrabass, tubax, slide, saxello, connosax,  saxophones. that doesnt include some of the variations in key